# developing Outlook Add in

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

How can i developed a plugin like the sales report or my links? i already developed a addin, but it goes to the menu. How can i insert it like that?

http://www.add-in-express.com/images/2007/adx-vsto/outlook/outlook-regions.gif

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the way to do this. This two websites help a lot to accomplish that.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338197%28office.12%29.aspx

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vsto/thread/b72b048f-f439-4417-970a-fea57a8b2bec

Answer (score 0):

Well, the screenshot you linked is already from a site that tells you one way to do it...

ADX is an amazing component set that's worth every single penny (also check their [discounts page](http://www.add-in-express.com/purchase/discounts.php))!

I guess I should add that I am not affiliated with Add-in-Express. I am just a happy user of their product and was a bit surprised that you linked to their site yet asked exactly for what they're offering. They even have extensive [video tutorials](http://www.add-in-express.com/support/video-howto-samples.php) on how to create Outlook form regions.

Maybe you should rephrase your question? Maybe you want to know how to achieve that same effect without using ADX?

Comment: @Luis: What do you mean? ADX is a framework for building Office addins. Among other things it allows visual drag&drop development of Outlook form regions (which is the name of the thing you're looking for).

Comment: yes, that was just a example, how can i do something like that

Comment: @Luis: just follow the link to the video tutorials - there are several of them about creating Outlook regions depending on what technology you're using (e.g. plain .NET or VSTO) and which Outlook window (Explorer or Inspector) you want to integrate with

Comment: but i dont want to buy it.. its too much to me, for what I want to do. How can i do it in visual studio?

Comment: @Luis: Ah OK, that's what I've been asking about all along (though you might still be surprised by the info on the discount page: it's perfectly possible to get ADX for free, e.g. simply by blogging about it). I haven't ever created Outlook regions without ADX so would have to look that up myself first. I'll do that later and add the info here. In the meantime I recommend searching MSDN for "Outlook regions" or "Outlook form regions".

Answer (score 0):

You need to developed Com Addin using Addin Express. I have done similar thing. You can subscribe either standard version of Pro version of Addin Express
https://www.add-in-express.com/add-in-net/index.php